# How to use drop down tabs as filter for listview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

Here is what I have as of right now.  My listview would populate normally when used above onitemselected, but when I comment it out or when I try to use the where clause methods in the spinner onitemselected it doesn't work.

Activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview_supports);

    try {
        openDB();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

//populateListFromDbSupports();


    final Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.typeArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(ViewSupports.this,
                    "You selected " + spinner2.getSelectedItem(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            final String type = (String) spinner2.getSelectedItem();

            final ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

            if (type.equals("One-Hole"))
                im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a167));
            //populateOneHole();
            if (type.equals("Two-Hole"))
                im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.twohole));
            populateTwoHole();
            if (type.equals("One-Piece Strut"))
                im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a174));
            if (type.equals("Two-Piece Strut"))
                im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a131));
            if (type.equals("Mineralac"))
                im.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a116));


//                myCursorAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
//                    @Override
//                    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
//                        return DB.fetchSupportsBySize(type);
//
//                    }
//                });
            Log.d(null, type, null);
            //DB.fetchSupportsBySize(type);


        }




        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
```

adapter

```
public static Cursor fetchSupportsBySize(String inputText) throws     SQLiteException {
    Log.w(TAG, inputText);
    Cursor mCursor = null;
    if (inputText == null ||inputText.length() == 0) {
        mCursor = db.query(SUPPORT_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_SUPPORT_ROWID, KEY_SUPPORT_SIZE, KEY_SUPPORT_TYPE, KEY_SUPPORT_MANUFACTURER, KEY_SUPPORT_PARTNUMBER},
                null, null, null, null, null);
    }
    else  {
        mCursor = db.query(true, SUPPORT_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_SUPPORT_ROWID, KEY_SUPPORT_SIZE, KEY_SUPPORT_TYPE, KEY_SUPPORT_MANUFACTURER, KEY_SUPPORT_PARTNUMBER},
                KEY_SUPPORT_SIZE + inputText, null, null, null, null, null);



    }
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}

public static Cursor fetchAllSupports() {
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(SUPPORT_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_SUPPORT_ROWID, KEY_SUPPORT_SIZE, KEY_SUPPORT_TYPE, KEY_SUPPORT_MANUFACTURER, KEY_SUPPORT_PARTNUMBER},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}



public static Cursor getAllSupportsBySize() {
    return db.query(SUPPORT_TABLE, null, "support_size=?", new String[]{"1/2"}, null, null, null);

}
public static Cursor getOneHoles() {
    return db.query(SUPPORT_TABLE, null, "support_type=?", new String[]{"One-Hole"}, null, null, null);

}
public static Cursor getTwoHoles() {
    return db.query(SUPPORT_TABLE, null, "support_type=?", new String[]{"Two-Hole"}, null, null, null);

}
    });










}
```

Comment: This is not so complicated, use a filter query provider backed by a like query and pass the `String` from your spinner. You must use `listView.setFilterEnabled(true);`

Comment: [Here](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-cursoradapter-sqlite.html) is an example, simply replace the `EditText` with  a `Spinner` and fetch the `Spinner` text on selection - pass this text to your `filterQueryProvider`. Using a like query or a where clause is upto you and depends on your use case, if you have exact word matches you can do away with the like clause.

Comment: I think I understand how the example is working.  I see that when it fetches data from the database it is fetching it all in one query.  In my application there are several cursors, one for each column.  I'm not sure I can use Lazy Adapter like that.  I'm lost..  I will have to look at the example tomorrow to play around with it and do some research.

Comment: Skynet can you help me?  Please.  You gave me good direction I think I just need a little more

Comment: Yes mate, just let me know where you are stuck?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the filterquery working with the spinner.  I modified my listview so that now I am not complicating things by pulling images from the Internet.  I don't know if I should copy over my old question like I did already or if I should post somewhere else, but I need help setting up the database filter query to work with my spinners.

Comment: Bro, I think the filter query approach is not feasible for your use case. Why dont you use a where clause and reload the list? For each of your query, each time fetching from the database and loading the list? As for the images you can use `UniversalImageLoader` for efficient loading of images both from the internet and local storage or even a content provider.

Comment: I'm sure you are right about my choice in using filter for this use case.  Using a where clause is what I was trying to understand a little bit.  As you can see in the above code I have a couple of where clauses that I was thinking I could use to populate the listview depending on spinner selection.  The problem that when I tried these methods in the database it didn't work properly.  I tried if statements that trigger the change of the image as well as re-populating the database and it didn't work.  There is a conflict somewhere..  I'm at the drawing board tonight!

Comment: I have methods with where clauses that would normally populate the listivew fine IF I put one of them in the oncreate method above the spinner onitemselected method.  The images switch just fine, but when I try to use the populate list view methods it doesn't populate at all.